# Yolov3 model over fitting with Cifar10 Dataset

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to implement Yolov3 using the cifar10 dataset for testing, when I run it the accuracy converges to 0.1 (always selecting the same class), the dataset size should not be an issue, I am not sure why the model would be doing this, I have confirmed that the rest of the code works fines on a smaller model however, is there anyway to get Yolov3 to work?

```
import cv2
import random
import struct
import mlxtend
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from mlxtend.data import loadlocal_mnist
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from keras.layers.merge import add, concatenate
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

data = cifar10
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.load_data()

train_images, test_images = train_images/255.0, test_images/255.0

def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 7, strides = 2, input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = 2))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 192, activation = 'relu', padding='same',  kernel_size = 3))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = 2))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 1))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 256, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 3))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 256, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 1))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 512, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 3))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = 2))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 256, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 1))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 512, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 3))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 256, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 1))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 512, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 3))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 256, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 1))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 512, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 3))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 256, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 1))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 512, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 3))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 512, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 1))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 1024, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 3))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = 2))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 512, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 1))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 1024, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 3))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 512, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 1))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 1024, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 3))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 1024, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 3))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 1024, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 3, strides = 2))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 1024, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 3))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 1024, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_size = 3))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(len(train_labels)))
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
 
model = create_model()

num_epochs = 5
batch_size = 32

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs = num_epochs, validation_split = 0.25, batch_size = batch_size)

results = model.evaulate(test_images, test_labels)
print("Test Accuracy:", results[1])
```

Comment: Have you checked what is the value of len(train_labels)? I do not think it is the number of classes.

Comment: That comes to 50,000 not 10 i'll switch it to 10 then run it and see what happens, Thanks!

Comment: The program is running a little faster but is still over fitting:                                      
Train on 37500 samples, validate on 12500 samples
Epoch 1/5
5408/37500 [===>..........................] - ETA: 2:05:56 - loss: 2.3026 - accuracy: 0.1043

Comment: What do you mean? You cannot determine overfitting until you see validation metrics, and that happens at the end of an epoch.

Comment: Epoch 1/3
37500/37500 [==============================] - 8459s 226ms/step - loss: 2.3026 - accuracy: 0.1004 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_accuracy: 0.0987
Epoch 2/3
37500/37500 [==============================] - 8432s 225ms/step - loss: 2.3026 - accuracy: 0.1004 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_accuracy: 0.0987
Epoch 3/3
37500/37500 [==============================] - 8430s 225ms/step - loss: 2.3026 - accuracy: 0.1004 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_accuracy: 0.0987